# Wrap multiple optional XML elements into a new wrapper XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file which looks like the following:

```
<a>
  ......
  <b>
    <c>
      <c1>some text</c1>
    </c>
    <d>
      <d1>some more text</d1>
      <d1>even more text</d1>
    </d>
    <e>
      <e1>some more text</e1>
      <e1>even more text</e1>
    </e>
  </b>
</a>
```

And I want to wrap elements `<d>` and `<e>` into a `<wrapper>` element, so I can have something like the following:

```
<a>
  ......
  <b>
    <c>
      <c1>some text</c1>
    </c>
    <wrapper>
      <d>
        <d1>some more text</d1>
        <d1>even more text</d1>
      </d>
      <e>
        <e1>some more text</e1>
        <e1>even more text</e1>
        <e2>even more</e2>
      </e>
    </wrapper>
  </b>
  ......
</a>
```

One of the problems that I'm facing (apart from the fact that I'm new to XSLT) is that both `<d>` and `<e>` are optional.

How can I do this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for complete and shot answer, using the most dundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern: the use and overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: In order to properly define this grouping question, I think you should clarify whether elements must be next siblings (group adjacent) or order doesn't count (group by pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b/*[self::d or self::e][1]">
  <wrapper>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
    ". | following-sibling::*[self::d or self::e]"/>
  </wrapper>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b/*[self::d or self::e][position()>1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>   ......   
    <b>
        <c>
            <c1>some text</c1>
        </c>
        <d>
            <d1>some more text</d1>
            <d1>even more text</d1>
        </d>
        <e>
            <e1>some more text</e1>
            <e1>even more text</e1>
        </e>
    </b>
</a>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<a>   ......   
    <b>
        <c>
            <c1>some text</c1>
        </c>
        <wrapper>
            <d>
                <d1>some more text</d1>
                <d1>even more text</d1>
            </d>
            <e>
                <e1>some more text</e1>
                <e1>even more text</e1>
            </e>
        </wrapper>
    </b>
</a>
```

**Note**: Overriden identity rule + modes.

Comment: +1 Better answer. This groups all siblings in the position of the first one. I would use a `xsl:call-template name="identity"` as `mode="copy"` content template in order to group in any hierarchy level.

Comment: Nice answer. Unfortunately, although it creates the hierarchy I want (with the extra wrapper element), it also leaves the original elements as they were. So, I'm getting the <wrapper>....</wrapper> and then I have <d>...</d><e>...</e>. Is there a reason for that? I should also point out that I actually have one more element below wrapper (something like <wrapper><subwrapper>....) but I updated your solution accordingly.

Comment: @Alex: I always test my code before posting an answer. The transformation, when applied to your XML document produces exactly the presented result. This result doesn't contain extraneous `d` and `e` elements. The only reason these appear to you can be that you modified the solution (without understanding its principles).

Comment: @Dimitre: Oh, actually I should apologize. I spoke without going into thoroughly examining the problem first. You are absolutely right! The code is working perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Because Dimitre post the group by pattern solution, I will go with the group by adjacent solution, just in case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[self::d|self::e][1]">
        <wrapper>
            <xsl:call-template name="group"/>
        </wrapper>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                        [not(self::d|self::e)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="group" name="group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]
                                                [self::d|self::e]"
                             mode="group"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<a>   ......   
    <b>
        <c>
            <c1>some text</c1>
        </c>
        <wrapper>
            <d>
                <d1>some more text</d1>
                <d1>even more text</d1>
            </d>
            <e>
                <e1>some more text</e1>
                <e1>even more text</e1>
            </e>
        </wrapper>
    </b>
</a>
```

**EDIT**: Shorter named template.

**Note**: This groups next siblings in original order in any hierarchy level. That means it could be several `wrapper` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply wrap an if test around it?

```
<wrapper>
    <xsl:if test="/a/b/d">
    <!-- write out the <d> node -->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/a/b/e">
    <!-- write out the <e> node -->
    </xsl:if>
</wrapper>
```